# Using Names() Function Deletes CSV

Tags: r

I'm am doing a programming assignment and have the following segments of code which should provide context to the data I'm using:

```
d <- read.csv(file='data6a.csv') # read and display data from CSV
d
```

This is what is displayed :
[image]
[image]

```
d = str(d)
d$colname=as.factor(d$colname)
```

[image]

**The issue arises here.** The assignment has given me this line of code to rename column x11 to y:

```
names(d)[names(d) == 'old.var.name'] <- 'new.var.name'
```

I have modified the code do to so:

```
names(d)[names(d) == 'x11'] <- 'y'
```

However, when I check to see that the column names are updated using `str(d)` as the assignment directs me, I am given the following output:

> List of 1
>
> $ colname: Factor w/ 0 levels:

This seems super straightforward yet I'm unsure why this is occurring. The code has basically been given to me other than that section I modified. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: The line `d = str(d)` is assigning the structure? but `str` doesn't have a return value i.e. `d <- iris; d <- str(d);> d#
NULL`.  According to `?str` - `str does not return anything, for efficiency reasons. The obvious side effect is output to the terminal.`

Comment: @akrun I tried just using `str(d)`, but I got this error in return: `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(\`*tmp*\`, colname, value = integer(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 394`

Comment: your line of code `d = str(d)` seems to be the issue as `d` is now NULL because `str` doesn't return anything.  Also, in the original data image, I don't find a column named `colname`

Comment: @akrun for some context, the assignment specifies "Apply the function 'str' to d to check that the categorical columns are now factors"

Comment: If you are checking with `str`, that is fine, but your code is updating the original object 'd' with `str` which doesn't have return value

Comment: Suppose you want to change the 'x11' column after reading i.e. `d <- read.csv(file='data6a.csv'); names(d)[names(d) == "x11"] <- "y"` should work

Comment: @akrun This makes sense now, thanks for the help. I managed to find a workaround based on what you've mentioned. I'll write an answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @akrun, the issue was identified.

When performing `d = str(d)`, `d` is set to null as `str()` does not return anything.

Changing the code to the following still has issues:

```
str(d)
d$colname=as.factor(d$colname)
```

as it returns:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, colname, value = integer(0)) : >replacement has 0 rows, data has 394

Because this assignment requires me to redefine each categorical variable as a factor, we cannot skip over that segment and just change the column names using `names(d)[names(d) == 'x11'] <- 'y`.`

The solution that worked for me was the following:

```
temp = str(d)
temp$colname=as.factor(temp$colname)
```

The code above displayed the categorical columns as factors in the variable `temp` so we can apply the line `names(d)[names(d) == 'x11'] <- 'y'` to `d` as it originally was.

Answer (score 1):

Things are getting messy from the point you're assigning  `d <-str(d)` because str will return the summary of of the output but should not be assigned to an object, from that point d is not a dataframe anymore.

Just run the code as following

```
d <- read.csv(file='data6a.csv')
names(d)[names(d) == 'x11'] <- 'y'
```

If you want to view the data just run `str(d)` but do not assign it to anything

Comment: Thanks for your time. Though this is technically right (and honestly should have been fine), the assignment needed for me to redefine each categorical variable as a factor so we can't skip that part

Comment: to redefine categorical variables as factors you should not assign str(d) to a any object, because that will return an empty object, you should redefine the variables from the dataframe not an empty object.